# Is MVC in node.js important for deveolping a restful api?

Tags: node.js, api, express, flutter, model-view-controller

I am learning node.js but I am not interested in web development, I learn it to use as a server or a backend for my mobile apps.

The course I follow includes a module about MVC (Model View Controller) and I want to know if it is important for developing an api using express and then use it in my app or not?

I am a flutter app developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to develop only a backend without a view then you need not follow the MVC model since you don't need the V in MVC. You can just develop routes in express which call your controllers.